# that durn my skin if I can keep my eyes from her if she wants them!

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Darned if the squaw hain't got on all her war paint! Jest give 
her a shove off if she comes any of her tricks on me, for I'm so 
fixed everlastingly by the boss, **that durn my skin if I can keep my eyes from her if she wants them!** Easy there. Judge! don't you slack that ar rope or I'm euchered!"

---

Another question about 'Squaw' by Bram Stoker.

Anybody can give me an explantion of the sentence above (block letter part)?

Looks simple, but it is undecipherable for me.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/m only guessing, but "durn my skin" looks like a [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath), probably replacing something like "damn my soul".

So the meaning is something like "I'll be damned if I can keep my eyes off her", i.e. "I can't keep my eyes off her".

"If she wants them" is a bit puzzling too, but I think it must mean "If she wants my eyes on her".